# Using a R.dot(vector) on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I got a Dataframe containg data for multiple entities in x,y,z direction with time as index similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,10), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("foo","x"),("foo","y"),("foo","z"),("bar","x"),("bar","y"),("bar","z")]), data=np.random.rand(10,6))
        foo                           bar                    
          x         y         z         x         y         z
0  0.972557  0.711319  0.190318  0.134453  0.903132  0.847353
1  0.922516  0.369936  0.940566  0.847049  0.180356  0.925252
2  0.843484  0.817282  0.245280  0.614433  0.959601  0.571053
3  0.409911  0.643583  0.723806  0.652375  0.532277  0.278601
4  0.322778  0.270078  0.822233  0.224622  0.808430  0.786399
5  0.323539  0.009899  0.175882  0.897813  0.287025  0.648503
6  0.180822  0.199223  0.573267  0.739941  0.479798  0.048885
7  0.961212  0.085247  0.092500  0.629304  0.582119  0.788289
8  0.960532  0.558652  0.676768  0.235705  0.255208  0.232676
9  0.213508  0.042688  0.238658  0.685202  0.760240  0.860439
```

what i need to do is to use a rotation matrix different for every entity to rotate the x,y,z data and replace the old values with the new ones. currently done for each index individual like so:

```
for entity in df.columns.levels[0]:
    R = np.matrix("[-0.70710678,-0.70710678,0.];[0.70710678,-0.70710678,0.];[0.,0.,1.]")
    for row in df.index:
                try:
                    vector = np.array(
                        [[df.loc[row, (entity, x)]], [df.loc[row, (entity, y)]], [df.loc[row, (entity, z)]]])
                    rvector = R.dot(vector)
                    df.loc[row, (entity, x)] = complex(rvector[0])
                    df.loc[row, (entity, y)] = complex(rvector[1])
                    df.loc[row, (entity, z)] = complex(rvector[2])
                except ValueError as e:
                    logger.error(e)
                    logger.debug(f"{vector} {R} {row}")
```

I tried to come up with a simpler/faster approach. I got a dataframe with 174 entities and 1255 time steps, with my current implementatio it takes about 1min to do the calculation for one entity. Where the hole three columns would be worked at the same time, but i could figure it out.

EDIT: added examble matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more trying got got a solution:

```
    entity_data = df.loc[:, entity]
    data = R.dot(entity_data.transpose()).transpose()
    entity_data_new = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=entity_data.index,
                                   columns=entity_data.columns)
    df.loc[:, entity] = entity_data_new.values
```

this should reduce the computing time to near linear time